# Infinite platform 3d

Tags: unity, c#

How do we make a infinite platform generator using prefabs. So ,for example, you have 3 prefabs and it generates a infinite platform by randomly generating the 3 prefabs.

This might come as a shock, but I did search it up and found nothing good or as explanatory.

Comment: In which part do you need help exactly, the randomisation or generating the path?

Comment: @S.Tarik Cetin generating the path

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure about your questions, so i will assume something below first according to common situation.

1. Your prefabs are a group of multiple objects which big enough to contain player character and take the whole screen.
2. Your character are actually moving forward, and the camera following it. (In some case, it could be character and camera remain still and scene moving backward)

### Path Generating

1. At game begin, arrange all prefab instances as one line randomly, like 3,1,2
2. With character moving, get past instance 3 and instance 1 the camera view come to the end of instance 2. At this time, randomly pick a prefab from prefabs except current prefab, which is {3,1} in this case. (you can also include instance 2, and that means you need to allow cloning instance 2, and releasing).
3. Move it (or clone it) to the end of instance 2.

### Randomisation

As a side note since your didn't mention it.

**easy way**: random pick equally each time

**hard way**: design a **Director AI** to make decision, which pretty like someone well prepared a level first and adjust it according to your behavior during playing. It will consider player interest, player emotion, level variety, drama plot.

you may choose some way between these two, depending on your situation.

### Implementation

Here's sample pseudo code for Path Generating

#### OnGameBegin

```
Instances = instance(obj) for obj in Prefabs // {1, 2, 3}
Instances.random_sort() // 3, 1, 2
// Here for simplicity, We start from the last one, which is 2
Instances.foreach((instance&, i)=>{instance.setPos(Vec3.X * -i)})
```

#### OnUpdate

```
if (currFocusInstance.End - MainCamera.Pos <= 0.5f * ViewScreen.Width):
    //Camera came to the end of current focus instance
    nextInstance = Pick(Instances - {currFocusInstance});
    nextInstance.setBegin(currFoucsInstance.End)
```

Comment: You certainly got what I mean. But I didn't exactly get what you mean.  Can you accompany your explanation with some code.

Comment: @AJ123 you mean path generating or randomisation?

Comment: Path generation

Comment: @AJ123 i add some python style pseudo code although you maybe use c# in your project，it's for simplicity

Comment: I do get it now, but I have no idea how to do this. It will be great if someone can translate this into a c sharp code.

Comment: @AJ123 maybe try it yourself since you already got it

Comment: I am saying this because I tried

Comment: @AJ123 so which step did you stuck in? can you instance prefabs and arrange them at correct position now?

Comment: Well, I can do that manually, the first time. But getting the pathway in front is the obvious hard part

Comment: @AJ123 so it's nothing about translating, but stucked in low details?  and "getting the pathway in front" means pathway switching or pathway picking and moving or something else? is that possible  to show us which step you are now according to pseudo code?